# Playwright: Selector for an element inside a specific div

Tags: playwright, playwright-typescript

let's assume I have multiple p-elements with the same text on my page and I want to check the visibility of a specific one that has to be inside a section-element.

```
<section class="contact__block">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>This is the one I'm looking for!</p>
    <p>...</p>
</section>
```

In addition: none of the p-elements inside the section is named or has an id. Is this possible and how does the selector look like?

Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: And how do you know what's the specific one? Are you looking for a specific text?

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention it! Yes, there are bunch of p-elements with the same text but only one of them lives inside the mentioned section.

Comment: It's unclear what the requirements are that make one `<p>` more special than the others. That's critical for writing an answer because it changes how you go about selecting it. Current answers are just guessing whether it's the text, child index position or what. So this seems to require more clarification, preferably an attempt at selecting it (you can use codegen). It's also hard to make a recommendation from such a tiny snippet without larger structural context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more Playwright-esque approach would be:

```js
page.locator("section").getByText("This is the one I'm looking for!")
```

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to use `nth()`, if the index number of the specific `<p>` element is static:

```
page.locator('section p').nth(1)
```

or to use `filter()` to get the needed from the list of `<p>` elements

```
page.locator('section p').filter({ hasText: 'This is the one I\'m looking for!' })
```

or to look for it by text, as was already advised:

```
page.locator('section').getByText('This is the one I\'m looking for!')
```

But the best solution would be to add a custom attribute(id, class, data-* attribute) for these elements, so you can easily identify them

Answer (score 0):

Think I found an answer, just don't know if it's the best possible solution:

```
page.locator('.contact__block >> p:has-text("This is the one I'm looking for!")')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

`await page.locator("section").locator("p").filter({hasText: "my text goes here"});`

Or even get it all in one locator:

`await page.locator("section>p").filter({hasText: "my text goes here"});`

I would recommend using getByRole where possible. As i dont know the inferred role from your html, I just went with locator. Something like the above will get you on the right path!